# How do I transition an animation upon clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an animation effect on the text: "Bluebox". It constantly transitions to different colors. I wish to get this text to transition into a blue color upon clicking the submit button. (note; submit button takes you to next page) However, the bluebox color animation completely breaks once I add this JS and css below.

```js
$('.submitbutton').click(function(e) {
  $submit = $(this);
  e.preventDefault();
  $('form').animate({
    opacity: "0"
  }, {
    duration: "slow",
    $("text color-text-flow").addclass('BBblue'),
    complete: function() {
      $submit.parents('form').submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@keyframes Blueboxblue {
  from {
    color: '';
  }
  to {
    color: blue
  }
}

.BBblue {
  animation: Blueboxblue ease 2s;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>BlueBox</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./newstyle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body class="indexbody">
    <div class="login">
        <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
        <form id="form1" action="authenticate.php" method="post">
            <label for="username">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required>
            <label for="password">
                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
            </label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
            <button type="submit" class="submitbutton">
                    <i class="fas fa-door-closed"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-door-open"></i>
                </button>
        </form>
    </div>
<div class="container">
  <span class="text color-text-flow">BlueBox</span>
</div>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e45d95b6b7.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is "my" code thats working without the above js/css in case you require it!:)

```js
$('.text').html(function(i, html) {
  var chars = $.trim(html).split("");
  return '<span>' + chars.join('</span><span>') + '</span>';
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "segoe ui", roboto, oxygen, ubuntu, cantarell, "fira sans", "droid sans", "helvetica neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen);
.color-text-flow,
.color-text-flow-hover:hover {
  /*
   * Elements settings
   */
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.color-text-flow span,
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-animation-name: color-text-flow-keys;
  animation-name: color-text-flow-keys;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 50s;
  animation-duration: 50s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes color-text-flow-keys {
  0% {
    color: #d65c97;
  }
  5% {
    color: #5cd666;
  }
  10% {
    color: #a55cd6;
  }
  15.0% {
    color: #5c7cd6;
  }
  20% {
    color: #d65c7a;
  }
  25% {
    color: #81d65c;
  }
  30.0% {
    color: #835cd6;
  }
  35% {
    color: #685cd6;
  }
  40% {
    color: #5c9dd6;
  }
  45% {
    color: #5cd670;
  }
  50% {
    color: #d6625c;
  }
  55.0% {
    color: #d6835c;
  }
  60.0% {
    color: #d6605c;
  }
  65% {
    color: #be5cd6;
  }
  70% {
    color: #5c8dd6;
  }
  75% {
    color: #95d65c;
  }
  80% {
    color: #d69d5c;
  }
  85.0% {
    color: #d65c81;
  }
  90% {
    color: #5cd666;
  }
  95% {
    color: #d67e5c;
  }
  100% {
    color: #64d65c;
  }
}

@keyframes color-text-flow-keys {
  0% {
    color: #d65c97;
  }
  5% {
    color: #5cd666;
  }
  10% {
    color: #a55cd6;
  }
  15.0% {
    color: #5c7cd6;
  }
  20% {
    color: #d65c7a;
  }
  25% {
    color: #81d65c;
  }
  30.0% {
    color: #835cd6;
  }
  35% {
    color: #685cd6;
  }
  40% {
    color: #5c9dd6;
  }
  45% {
    color: #5cd670;
  }
  50% {
    color: #d6625c;
  }
  55.0% {
    color: #d6835c;
  }
  60.0% {
    color: #d6605c;
  }
  65% {
    color: #be5cd6;
  }
  70% {
    color: #5c8dd6;
  }
  75% {
    color: #95d65c;
  }
  80% {
    color: #d69d5c;
  }
  85.0% {
    color: #d65c81;
  }
  90% {
    color: #5cd666;
  }
  95% {
    color: #d67e5c;
  }
  100% {
    color: #64d65c;
  }
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(1),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -19.8s;
  animation-delay: -19.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(2),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -19.6s;
  animation-delay: -19.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(3),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -19.4s;
  animation-delay: -19.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(4),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -19.2s;
  animation-delay: -19.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(5),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -19s;
  animation-delay: -19s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(6),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(6) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -18.8s;
  animation-delay: -18.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(7),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(7) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -18.6s;
  animation-delay: -18.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(8),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(8) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -18.4s;
  animation-delay: -18.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(9),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(9) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -18.2s;
  animation-delay: -18.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(10),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(10) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -18s;
  animation-delay: -18s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(11),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(11) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -17.8s;
  animation-delay: -17.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(12),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(12) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -17.6s;
  animation-delay: -17.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(13),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(13) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -17.4s;
  animation-delay: -17.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(14),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(14) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -17.2s;
  animation-delay: -17.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(15),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(15) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -17s;
  animation-delay: -17s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(16),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(16) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -16.8s;
  animation-delay: -16.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(17),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(17) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -16.6s;
  animation-delay: -16.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(18),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(18) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -16.4s;
  animation-delay: -16.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(19),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(19) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -16.2s;
  animation-delay: -16.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(20),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(20) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -16s;
  animation-delay: -16s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(21),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(21) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -15.8s;
  animation-delay: -15.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(22),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(22) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -15.6s;
  animation-delay: -15.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(23),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(23) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -15.4s;
  animation-delay: -15.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(24),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(24) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -15.2s;
  animation-delay: -15.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(25),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(25) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -15s;
  animation-delay: -15s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(26),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(26) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -14.8s;
  animation-delay: -14.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(27),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(27) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -14.6s;
  animation-delay: -14.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(28),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(28) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -14.4s;
  animation-delay: -14.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(29),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(29) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -14.2s;
  animation-delay: -14.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(30),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(30) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -14s;
  animation-delay: -14s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(31),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(31) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -13.8s;
  animation-delay: -13.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(32),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(32) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -13.6s;
  animation-delay: -13.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(33),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(33) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -13.4s;
  animation-delay: -13.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(34),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(34) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -13.2s;
  animation-delay: -13.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(35),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(35) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -13s;
  animation-delay: -13s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(36),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(36) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -12.8s;
  animation-delay: -12.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(37),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(37) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -12.6s;
  animation-delay: -12.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(38),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(38) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -12.4s;
  animation-delay: -12.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(39),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(39) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -12.2s;
  animation-delay: -12.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(40),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(40) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -12s;
  animation-delay: -12s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(41),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(41) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -11.8s;
  animation-delay: -11.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(42),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(42) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -11.6s;
  animation-delay: -11.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(43),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(43) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -11.4s;
  animation-delay: -11.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(44),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(44) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -11.2s;
  animation-delay: -11.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(45),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(45) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -11s;
  animation-delay: -11s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(46),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(46) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -10.8s;
  animation-delay: -10.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(47),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(47) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -10.6s;
  animation-delay: -10.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(48),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(48) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -10.4s;
  animation-delay: -10.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(49),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(49) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -10.2s;
  animation-delay: -10.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(50),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(50) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -10s;
  animation-delay: -10s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(51),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(51) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -9.8s;
  animation-delay: -9.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(52),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(52) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -9.6s;
  animation-delay: -9.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(53),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(53) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -9.4s;
  animation-delay: -9.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(54),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(54) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -9.2s;
  animation-delay: -9.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(55),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(55) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -9s;
  animation-delay: -9s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(56),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(56) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -8.8s;
  animation-delay: -8.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(57),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(57) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -8.6s;
  animation-delay: -8.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(58),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(58) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -8.4s;
  animation-delay: -8.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(59),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(59) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -8.2s;
  animation-delay: -8.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(60),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(60) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -8s;
  animation-delay: -8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(61),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(61) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -7.8s;
  animation-delay: -7.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(62),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(62) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -7.6s;
  animation-delay: -7.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(63),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(63) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -7.4s;
  animation-delay: -7.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(64),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(64) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -7.2s;
  animation-delay: -7.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(65),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(65) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -7s;
  animation-delay: -7s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(66),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(66) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -6.8s;
  animation-delay: -6.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(67),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(67) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -6.6s;
  animation-delay: -6.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(68),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(68) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -6.4s;
  animation-delay: -6.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(69),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(69) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -6.2s;
  animation-delay: -6.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(70),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(70) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -6s;
  animation-delay: -6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(71),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(71) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -5.8s;
  animation-delay: -5.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(72),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(72) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -5.6s;
  animation-delay: -5.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(73),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(73) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -5.4s;
  animation-delay: -5.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(74),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(74) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -5.2s;
  animation-delay: -5.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(75),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(75) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -5s;
  animation-delay: -5s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(76),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(76) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4.8s;
  animation-delay: -4.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(77),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(77) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4.6s;
  animation-delay: -4.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(78),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(78) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4.4s;
  animation-delay: -4.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(79),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(79) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4.2s;
  animation-delay: -4.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(80),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(80) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -4s;
  animation-delay: -4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(81),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(81) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3.8s;
  animation-delay: -3.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(82),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(82) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3.6s;
  animation-delay: -3.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(83),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(83) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3.4s;
  animation-delay: -3.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(84),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(84) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3.2s;
  animation-delay: -3.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(85),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(85) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -3s;
  animation-delay: -3s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(86),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(86) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2.8s;
  animation-delay: -2.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(87),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(87) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2.6s;
  animation-delay: -2.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(88),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(88) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2.4s;
  animation-delay: -2.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(89),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(89) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2.2s;
  animation-delay: -2.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(90),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(90) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
  animation-delay: -2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(91),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(91) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.8s;
  animation-delay: -1.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(92),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(92) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.6s;
  animation-delay: -1.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(93),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(93) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.4s;
  animation-delay: -1.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(94),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(94) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.2s;
  animation-delay: -1.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(95),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(95) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
  animation-delay: -1s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(96),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(96) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(97),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(97) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.6s;
  animation-delay: -0.6s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(98),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(98) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.4s;
  animation-delay: -0.4s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(99),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(99) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.2s;
  animation-delay: -0.2s;
}

.color-text-flow span:nth-of-type(100),
.color-text-flow-hover:hover span:nth-of-type(100) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.indexbody {
  background-color: #EDF1FF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20;
  top: 34%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="indexbody">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="text color-text-flow">BlueBox</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `addclass` needs to be `addClass`, JS is case-sensitive. For future reference, if you ever have JS code that isn't working as expected, check the console in dev tools for errors; generally under the F12 key in your browser. In this case there would be an 'addclass is not a function' error.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML - this is not valid jQuery selector `$("text color-text-flow")`

Comment: Thank you for the advice, Rory. mplungjan, I have added the html to the snippet. Sorry, it took me a while to realise you did a whole revision because I didn't know that was a function on this website lol. (thank you for your time btw!!!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button don't have to be type submit, any button can trigger form submission.
Also, `addclass` should be `addClass`

```js
$('.submitbutton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".textdisplay").addClass('BBblue');
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#form1').submit(); }, 2000);
});
```

```css
@keyframes Blueboxblue {
  from {
    color: '';
  }
  to {
    color: blue
  }
}

.BBblue {
  animation: Blueboxblue ease 2s infinite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="textdisplay">this is a test</span>

<form id="form1">
<button class="submitbutton">Submit</button>
</form>
```